# Test if a skip has an infinite stretch/shrink component

Tags: conditionals, lengths

I want to implement an if-then-else depending on whether a skip contains a special character or not.

So far, I tried the idea: convert the skip to a token list, and check if the letter `f` is in the list. Something like this:

```
\leftskip=10pt plus1fil\relax
\edef\mystring{\the\leftskip\the\rightskip}
\if\instring{f}{\mystring}\message{YES}\else\message{NO}\fi
\def\mystring{10.0pt plus 1.0fil}
\if\instring{f}{\mystring}\message{YES}\else\message{NO}\fi
\message{\the\leftskip}
```

I use `\mystring` as defined here: [Check if a string contains a given character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/check-if-a-string-contains-a-given-character)

Unfortunately, the code does not work. The log file contains contains `NO` instead of `YES`:

```
NO
YES
10.0pt plus 1.0fil
```

Probably I know what is wrong, but it is time to ask for a better idea: how to detect infinity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The catcode of `f` is 11 for "letter". However, the tokens output by `\the` have catcode 12 (other character) with the exception of the space with catcode 10.
For your comparison the catcode of `f` can be "converted" to `12` by `\string`:

```
\if\expandafter\instring\string f{\mystring}
```

### Test with e-TeX

e-TeX provides `\gluestretchorder` and `\glueshrinkorder` return the order of infinity, e.g. the values of `\gluestretchorder` reflects the infinity of the `plus` component:

- `0`: no `fil`, `fill`, ...
- `1`: `fil`
- `2`: `fill`
- `3`: `filll`

The following way can be tested, whether a skip contains an infinite stretch component (using `\leftskip` as example for a skip register):

```
\ifnum\gluestretchorder\leftskip>0 %
  \message{YES}%
\else
  \message{NO}%
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks you, I'm very happy to learn about glueorder-commands.