# Auto generate List of \url usages within document

Tags: urls

I am writing a thesis and I have made extensive use of hyperlinking through `\url` or `\url` within a `\footnote`. Now I would like to add a list (kind of like a simplified bibliography where each link appears only once) of all hyperlinks within the document. Is there a way to have that automatically generated for me?

Comment: Do you have duplicate `\url`s in your document?

Comment: Yes. There are a small handful of duplicates.

Comment: What if we redefine `\url` to include a `\index` entry? That way, we can have a list of URL's followed by their occurrences. `:)`

Comment: That sounds promising, unfortunately it also exceeds my proficiency in LaTeX. How would I redefine \url in that way? `\newcommand{\url}{\url \index}`?

Comment: @typR That will give you an infinite loop. You'd have to do something like `\let\oldurl\url\renewcommand{\url}[1]{\oldurl{#1}\index{#1}}` but if any of your urls contain characters such as `~` or `@` extra coding is required.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. The following example uses `hyperref` (the question has mentioned "hyperlinking") and hooks into `\hyper@linkurl` to get the URLs.
2. The catched URLs are written into an index file `\jobname-url.idx`:

   ```
   \urlentry{<hex coded URL>}{<page number>}
   ```

   The URL are hex encoded to avoid trouble with special characters.
3. Package `filecontents` helps to create a style file `\jobname-url.mst` for `makeindex`. Makeindex automatically looks for a file with the same name as the input file, but with extension `.mst` as style file. Then only the `.idx` file needs to be given as argument for `makeindex`.
4. Makeindex generates the file `\jobname-url.ind`:

   ```
   \begin{theurls}
   \urlitem{<hex coded URL>}{<page list>}
   ...
   \end{theurls}
   ```
5. Environment `theurls` and `\urlitem` are defined appropriately to print the list of urls. `\listurlname` contains the title of the section.

**Remarks**:

- Makeindex takes care of the sorting and removes duplicates.
- Hooking into `\hyper@linkurl` has the advantage, that the URL is normalized
  (e.g., `%` and `\%` are the same, a `%` with catcode 12/other).
- Hex encoding has the advantage, that special characters such as percent,
  hash or characters with special meaning for makeindex (at sign, ...) do not
  need a special treatment.

Example file:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-url.mst}
% Input style specifiers
keyword "\\urlentry"
% Output style specifiers
preamble "\\begin{theurls}"
postamble "\\end{theurls}\n"
group_skip ""
headings_flag 0  
item_0 "\n\\urlitem{"
delim_0 "}{"
delim_t "}"
line_max 500
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfescape}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\file@url
\openout\file@url=\jobname-url.idx\relax

\newcommand*{\write@url}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \EdefEscapeHex\@tmp{#1}%
    \protected@write\file@url{}{%
      \protect\urlentry{\@tmp}{\thepage}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\let\saved@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl
\renewcommand*{\hyper@linkurl}[2]{%
  \write@url{#2}%
  \saved@hyper@linkurl{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\listurlname}{List of URLs}
\newcommand*{\printurls}{%
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname-url.ind}{}{}%
}
\newenvironment{theurls}{%
  \section*{\listurlname}%
  \@mkboth{\listurlname}{\listurlname}%
  \let\write@url\@gobble  
  \ttfamily
  \raggedright
}{%
  \par
}
\newcommand*{\urlitem}[2]{%
  \hangindent=1em
  \hangafter=1   
  \begingroup    
    \EdefUnescapeHex\@tmp{#1}%
    \expandafter\url\expandafter{\@tmp}%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}

\begin{document}
This this file answers the
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121977/16967}{question}
on \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\TeX.SE}.

Further examples for URLs:
\url{http://www.dante.de/}\\
\url{http://www.ctan.org/}\\
\url{mailto:me@example.org/}\\
\url{ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/}\\
\url{http://www.example.com/\%7efoo/index.html}\\
\url{http://www.example.com/%7efoo/index.html} 

\printurls
\end{document}
```

The following commands generate the result (linux/bash):

```
$ pdflatex test
```

Generates `test-url.mst` and `test-url.idx`.

```
$ makeindex test-url
```

Generates `test-url.ind`.

```
$ pdflatex test
```

> [image: Result]

### Update for page numbers

There are many formatting ways for the page numbers. The following example uses dots to separate the URL from the page numbers that appear at the end of the line (similar to the index of package `doc`). As requested the page numbers are prefixed with `p.`, if only one page number follows and `pp.` otherwise. This is implented with the help of package `xstring` by testing the page number list, whether it contains a comma separator or a hyphen from a range specifier.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-url.mst}
% Input style specifiers
keyword "\\urlentry"
% Output style specifiers
preamble "\\begin{theurls}"
postamble "\n\\end{theurls}\n"
group_skip ""
headings_flag 0  
item_0 "\n\\urlitem{"
delim_0 "}{"
delim_t "}"
line_max 500
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfescape}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\file@url
\openout\file@url=\jobname-url.idx\relax

\newcommand*{\write@url}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \EdefEscapeHex\@tmp{#1}%
    \protected@write\file@url{}{%
      \protect\urlentry{\@tmp}{\thepage}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\let\saved@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl
\renewcommand*{\hyper@linkurl}[2]{%
  \write@url{#2}%
  \saved@hyper@linkurl{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\listurlname}{List of URLs}
\newcommand*{\printurls}{%
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname-url.ind}{}{}%
}
\newenvironment{theurls}{%
  \section*{\listurlname}%
  \@mkboth{\listurlname}{\listurlname}%
  \let\write@url\@gobble  
  \ttfamily
  \raggedright
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}%
}{%
  \par
}
\newcommand*{\urlitem}[2]{%
  \hangindent=1em
  \hangafter=1   
  \begingroup    
    \EdefUnescapeHex\@tmp{#1}%
    \expandafter\url\expandafter{\@tmp}%
  \endgroup
  \urlindex@pfill
  \IfSubStr{#2}{,}{pp}{%
    \IfSubStr{#2}{-}{pp}{p}%
  }.\@\space\ignorespaces
  #2%
  \par
}
\newcommand*{\urlindex@pfill}{% from \pfill of package `doc'
  \unskip~\urlindex@dotfill
  \penalty500\strut\nobreak
  \urlindex@dotfil~\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand*{\urlindex@dotfill}{% from \dotfill of package `doc'
  \leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss .\hss}\hskip\z@ plus  1fill\relax
}
\newcommand*{\urlindex@dotfil}{% from \dotfil of package `doc'
  \leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss .\hss}\hfil
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}

\begin{document}
This this file answers the
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121977/16967}{question}
on \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\TeX.SE}.

Further examples for URLs:
\url{http://www.dante.de/}\\
\url{http://www.ctan.org/}\\
\url{mailto:me@example.org/}\\
\url{ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/}\\
\url{http://www.example.com/\%7efoo/index.html}\\
\url{http://www.example.com/%7efoo/index.html} 

% further pages to generate more page numbers for testing the url index
\newpage
\url{http://www.ctan.org}
\newpage
\url{http://www.ctan.org}
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\newpage
\printurls

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with page numbers]

Comment: Wow! Absolutely fantastic! `:)`

Comment: How can you turn on printing of the page numbers?

Comment: I guess adding a `\space(p. #2)` to `\urlitem` is a minimal idea.  I'd like to have "pp." when there are multiple pages though... seems much more complicated though.  Hm... not so bad after all: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/check-if-a-string-contains-a-given-character

Comment: @JoeCorneli: I have updated the answer and added an example with page numbers that are preceded by `p.` or `pp.`.

Comment: Heiko: Would you be willing to comment on a related but more complex example?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146954/makeindex-print-links-sorted-by-page

Comment: This seems to be pretty good. Can this be made into a CTAN package? :)

Comment: @wilx In theory yes, it could make a new package, but currently I do not even have enough time for important updates of existing packages. At least I have put it on the ToDo list.

Comment: For those who want to have the index made and added automatically via `latexmk` (e.g., for sites like Overleaf), add the following to your code after the `\InputIfFileExists` line: `\wlog{} \wlog{Writing index file \jobname-url.idx}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have to agree with @wilx. Having this as a full blown package would be amazing. Especially if there's stuff that autodetects the right type of heading (like `/chapter` for `memoir` instead of `/section` for most classes). So is there any updated related to that?

Comment: This is super cool! For me it is picking up bibliography URLs, which is undesired, is it possible to limit the portion of the document it lists?

Answer (score 16):

[image: Warning] **Atention**: the following code works only for simple URLs, that is, URLs that do not contain special characters, like `%`. For a complete solution, please refer to Heiko's answer.

---

As Nicola mentioned in the comments, redefining `\url` might be an interesting idea, but some characters in the URL might cause problems. Sadly my TeX-fu isn't good enough to overcome this issue, but here's a preliminary start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\let\originalurl\url

\makeindex[name=urls, title={Links found in this document}, columns=1]

\renewcommand{\url}[1]{\originalurl{#1}\index[urls]{\protect\originalurl{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

Hello, make sure to visit \url{http://www.google.com} and,
of course, our own place \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}.

By the way, \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com} is awesome!

\printindex[urls]

\end{document}
```

The list is then generated:

[image: Links]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: This will have problems with special characters in the URL, particularly `%`. But +1 anyway.

Comment: @egreg: I know, but I have no idea on how to solve it. `:)` Is "Make sure to use URL shortening services for all URLs." a good excuse? `:)`

Comment: Dear downvoter, I really would like your help to improve my answer. Could you write down a few suggestions on what should I do in order to make my answer more adherent to a valid solution? Thanks. `:)`

Comment: The excuse is good. ;-) Long URLs should never appear in the main text.

Comment: +1 for the idea and the elegant clear simple approach (with the mentioned restriction).