# makeindex - print links sorted by page

Tags: indexing, sorting

[Auto generate List of \url usages within document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121977/auto-generate-list-of-url-usages-within-document/) describes a method for generating an index of URLs that are used in the document, including page number.  However, the URLs are sorted alphanumerically.  I'd like to make a URL index that sorts them per page, in the order in which the links appear on the page.  Furthermore, my links are actually in `\hrefs` and I would like to include the link text in the index:

```
p. 1
     Wikipedia... http://wikipedia.org
     SXE... http://stackexchange.com
p. 2
     Google... http://google.com
```

I've created a MWE following the instructions from Heiko Oberdiek in the post I linked to above (compile with `xelatex links.tex`, `makeindex links-url`, `xelatex links.tex`).  Note, the output I currently get is, as expected (but not desired) in alphabetical order rather than page order:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,article]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{11in}{8.5in}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{9in}{6.5in}{*}
\setlrmargins{1in}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{1in}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{1.5\onelineskip}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[linktoc=all,frenchlinks,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W .5},citebordercolor={1 1 1},linkbordercolor={1 1 1},urlbordercolor={1 1 1}]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-url.mst}
% Input style specifiers
keyword "\\urlentry"
% Output style specifiers
preamble "\\begin{theurls}"
postamble "\\end{theurls}\n"
group_skip ""
headings_flag 0
item_0 "\n\\urlitem{"
delim_0 "}{"
delim_t "}"
line_max 500
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pdfescape}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\file@url
\openout\file@url=\jobname-url.idx\relax

\def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}

\newcommand*{\write@url}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \EdefEscapeHex\@tmp{#1}%
    \protected@write\file@url{}{%
      \protect\urlentry{\@tmp}{\thepage}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\let\saved@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl
\renewcommand*{\hyper@linkurl}[2]{%
  \write@url{#2}%
  \saved@hyper@linkurl{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\listurlname}{List of URLs}
\newcommand*{\printurls}{%
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname-url.ind}{}{}%
}
\newenvironment{theurls}{%
  \begin{center}{\Huge \listurlname}%
\vspace{.7in}\\ \end{center}
{All of these links were active as of \today.} \\
\quad \\ \noindent
  %\section*{\listurlname}%
  \@mkboth{\listurlname}{\listurlname}%
  \let\write@url\@gobble
  \ttfamily\footnotesize
  \raggedright
  \hspace{-1.4em}
}{%
  \par
}
\newcommand*{\urlitem}[2]{%
  \hangindent=1em
  \hangafter=1
  \begingroup
    \urlpages{#2}%
    \EdefUnescapeHex\@tmp{#1}%
    \expandafter\url\expandafter{\@tmp}%
  \endgroup
  \newline
}
\newcommand*{\urlpages}[1]{%
{%
\normalfont
\space(\if\instring{,}{#1}{pp.\space#1}\else{p.\space\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}\fi)}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\href{http://wikipedia.org}{Wikipedia} \href{http://stackexchange.com}{SXE}  
\newpage
\href{http://google.com}{Google}

\section*{Index of URLs}
\printurls
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few different approaches, here is a rather hacky solution that works -- although it requires some by-hand editing of the `.ind` file, so there's room for improvement!

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\let\hrefold\href
\newcounter{IndexItemCounter}
\renewcommand*{\href}[2]{\stepcounter{IndexItemCounter}%
\hrefold{#1}{#2}\index{\thepage@{p. \thepage}%
!{\theIndexItemCounter}@{#2\ldots\ \url{#1}}}}
```

A few comments:

- There's no real need for the standard indexing feature which produces page numbers following each entry (for now I just delete those lines from the `.ind` file).
- `#` inside of URLs throws the indexing mechanism for a loop.

To make the display look reasonable I do a tiny bit of customization with `memoir`:

```
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Web Pages Cited in This Book}
\onecolindex
\printindex
```

I also added `\raggedright` at the top of the `.ind` file.

Comment: Note, using `\hyperlink{page.\thepage}{p. \thepage}` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since the URLs are not sorted alphabetically, sorting via Makeindex is not necessary. The page numbers only requires the label/reference system (two LaTeX runs).

The example stores for each URL the URL, text and page in a reference. Package `zref` allows arbitrary data fields in its references.

Then `\UrlList` prints the list of URLs. This can be configured by environment `UrlListEnv` and macros `\UrlListPage` and `\UrlListItem`. The example below uses a `description` environment with page description labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{zref-base,zref-lastpage}
\usepackage{etexcmds}
\usepackage{pdfescape}

\makeatletter

% Help counters for numbering URLs
\newcounter{UrlList}
\newcounter{UrlListAux}
\renewcommand*{\theUrlList}{UrlList\the\value{UrlList}}
\renewcommand*{\theUrlListAux}{UrlList\the\value{UrlListAux}}

% Each URL gets a reference with text, url and page number.
\zref@newprop{UrlList@Text}{\UrlList@Text}
\zref@newprop{UrlList@HexLink}[3F3F]{\UrlList@HexLink}
\zref@newlist{UrlList}
\zref@addprops{UrlList}{UrlList@Text, UrlList@HexLink, page}
\zref@newprop{UrlList@Max}{\the\value{UrlList}}
\zref@addprops{LastPage}{UrlList@Max}

% Switch is needed in the list of URLs to disable URL recording.
\newif\ifUrlList@

% Hyperref internal is redefined to write the label with the URL data
\newcommand\saved@hyper@linkurl{}
\let\saved@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl
\renewcommand{\hyper@linkurl}[2]{%
  % #1: text
  % #2: URL
  \ifUrlList@
  \else
    \begingroup
      \refstepcounter{UrlList}%
      \protected@edef\UrlList@Text{#1}%
      \@onelevel@sanitize\UrlList@Text
      \EdefEscapeHex\UrlList@HexLink{#2}%
      \zref@labelbylist{\theUrlList}{UrlList}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \saved@hyper@linkurl{#1}{#2}%
}

% \UrlList checks, whether are URL references and prints the list of URLs
\newcommand*{\UrlList}{%
  \zref@refused{LastPage}%
  \edef\UrlList@Max{%
    \zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{UrlList@Max}{-1}%
  }%
  \ifnum\UrlList@Max<0 %
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Rerun LaTeX to get list of URLs}%
  \else
    \UrlList@true
    \begin{UrlListEnv}%
      \let\UrlList@LastPage\@empty
      \setcounter{UrlListAux}{0}%
      \@whilenum\value{UrlListAux}<\UrlList@Max\do{%
        \stepcounter{UrlListAux}%
        \zref@refused{\theUrlListAux}%
        \zref@ifrefundefined{\theUrlListAux}{%
        }{%
          \EdefUnescapeHex\UrlList@Link{%
            \zref@extract{\theUrlListAux}{UrlList@HexLink}%
          }%
          \zref@def@extract\UrlList@Text{\theUrlListAux}{UrlList@Text}%
          \zref@def@extract\UrlList@Page{\theUrlListAux}{page}%
          \edef\UrlList@Next{%
            \noexpand\UrlListItem{%
              \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\UrlList@Page}%
            }{%
              \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\UrlList@Link}%
            }{%
              \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\UrlList@Text}%
            }%
          }%
          \ifx\UrlList@Page\UrlList@LastPage
          \else
            \expandafter\UrlListPage\expandafter{\UrlList@Page}%
            \let\UrlList@LastPage\UrlList@Page
          \fi
          \UrlList@Next
        }%
      }%
    \end{UrlListEnv}%
  \fi
}
\makeatletter

% USER configuration

% Environment UrlListEnv surrounds the list of URLs, if
% URLs are available.
\newenvironment{UrlListEnv}{%
  \begin{description}%
}{%
  \end{description}%
}

% \UrlListPage{<page>}
% Sets the page header
\newcommand*{\UrlListPage}[1]{%
  \item[\hyperlink{page.#1}{Page #1}]\mbox{}%
}

% \UrlListItem{<page>}{<URL>}{<text>}
% Formats a URL entry
\newcommand*{\UrlListItem}[3]{%
  \\\relax#3 \dots\ \href{#2}{\nolinkurl{#2}}%
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\href{http://wikipedia.org}{Wikipedia} \href{http://stackexchange.com}{SXE}  
\newpage
\href{http://google.com}{Google}

\section*{Index of URLs}
\UrlList
\end{document}
```

Result/page 2:

> [image: Result]

Comment: The command `\url` is not defined anymore. Logic because there is no key-text for the index list. But often it may be usefull to display the url in the text and listed the url also in the index with key-information. Is there a way to make `\url` command working with two arguments (url + key-text) also to display url in the document and the same listing as `\href` in the index ?