# Color in Url list

Tags: hyperref

I find this code 
I 've done few changes but I have some troubles with color.
I would like to have in my List of urls (liste de liens)

"lien 1 : " in black with spaces and the links in blue.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfescape}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
% Input style specifiers
keyword "\\urlentry"
% Output style specifiers
preamble "\\begin{theurls}"
postamble "\n\\end{theurls}\n"
group_skip ""
headings_flag 0  
item_0 "\n\\urlitem{"
delim_0 "}{"
delim_t "}"
line_max 500
\end{filecontents*}
\newcounter{compteururl}
\setcounter{compteururl}{0}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\file@url
\openout\file@url=\jobname.idx\relax

\newcommand*{\write@url}[1]{\addtocounter{compteururl}{1}%
  \begingroup
    \EdefEscapeHex\@tmp{\lien : #1}%
    \protected@write\file@url{}{%
      \protect\urlentry{\@tmp}{\thepage}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\let\saved@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl
\renewcommand*{\hyper@linkurl}[2]{%
  \write@url{#2}%
  \saved@hyper@linkurl{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\listurlname}{Liste des liens}
\newcommand*{\printurls}{%
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.ind}{}{}%
}
\newenvironment{theurls}{%
  \section*{\listurlname}%
  \@mkboth{\listurlname}{\listurlname}%
  \let\write@url\@gobble  
  \ttfamily
  \raggedright
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}%
}{%
  \par
}
\newcommand*{\urlitem}[2]{%
  \hangindent=1em
  \hangafter=1   
  \begingroup    
    \EdefUnescapeHex\@tmp{#1}%
    \expandafter\url\expandafter{\@tmp}%
  \endgroup
  \urlindex@pfill
  p.\@\space\ignorespaces
  #2%
  \par
}
\newcommand*{\urlindex@pfill}{%
  \unskip~\urlindex@dotfill
  \penalty500\strut\nobreak
  \urlindex@dotfil~\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand*{\urlindex@dotfill}{%
  \leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss .\hss}\hskip\z@ plus  1fill\relax
}
\newcommand*{\urlindex@dotfil}{% from \dotfil of package `doc'
  \leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss .\hss}\hfil
}



\newcommand\lien{lien \thecompteururl}
\makeatother

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}

\begin{document}
some texte with reference
\href{http://abc.com}{\lien}
and \href{http://zwy.com/}{\lien}.

\clearpage
some texte with reference
\href{http://koyc.com}{\lien}
and \href{http://pft.com/}{\lien}.
\clearpage
some texte with reference
\href{http://lyc.com}{\lien}
and \href{http://at.com/}{\lien}.

some texte with reference
\href{http://abc.com}{\lien}
and \href{http://abb.com/}{\lien}.

\newpage
\printurls

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you also provide the source where you found that piece of code?

Comment: as Im new here I can't post more than one link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121977/auto-generate-list-of-url-usages-within-document
I also woul have the link in order of appearance thank you

Comment: The numbering scheme and the sorting in the index is not clear at all. Example (a): Order of appearance; duplicates get the number of their first occurence; URL index is either sorted by numbers or URLs. Example (b): The URLs are ordered in the index and are numbered consecutively; in the text before, the URLs reference their number of the index.

Comment: excuse my poor english. I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Is there a  way to have my list of url in order of appearence of links in the text? and  print " lien 1 : " in black?

Comment: There are different ways to do this, but it depends on, how the list of URLs is sorted and how the URLs are numbered.

Comment: Also `\href` needs to detect URLs, e.g. the protocol is missing: `http://`. Thus `abc.com` is interpreted as file name.

Comment: I had to remove http:// cause it was my first message and i'm not allow to send more than one links.
all my links are with http://

Comment: @romainderc: I have added the prefixes. AFAIK you have now enough reputation for adding links. If you add two more links, then the links get sorted by the number *alphabetically*. Also duplicate links get listed for each occurrence. A sorted list of unique URLs is a complete different matter than a list of URLs in the order of appearance. The first needs sorting (e.g. via makeindex), the latter does not. And if a sorted index is numbered, then also a referencing mechanism (e,g. `\label`/`\ref`) is needed.

Comment: I have just written an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173719/16967) that solves question ["makeindex - print links sorted by page"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146954/16967) with a different algorithm, which lists the URLs in the order of appearance without using Makeindex.

Comment: @romainderc: Dos this mean, your problem is solved and the question can be closed as duplicate?

Comment: yes, or delete because your answer in the other post is great. Thank you