# Line breaks in urlindex

Tags: indexing

In this discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146954/makeindex-print-links-sorted-by-page), Heiko gave me a great answer, but now i have a line breaks problem. If I write `\href{http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006055121&dateTexte=20110206}{blabla}` I get an overfullhbox, and It's not very beautifull. Is There a way to fix it?
Thanks.
The mwe is in the link above.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{zref-base,zref-lastpage}
\usepackage{etexcmds}
\usepackage{pdfescape}

\makeatletter

% Help counters for numbering URLs
\newcounter{UrlList}
\newcounter{UrlListAux}
\renewcommand*{\theUrlList}{UrlList\the\value{UrlList}}
\renewcommand*{\theUrlListAux}{UrlList\the\value{UrlListAux}}

% Each URL gets a reference with text, url and page number.
\zref@newprop{UrlList@Text}{\UrlList@Text}
\zref@newprop{UrlList@HexLink}[3F3F]{\UrlList@HexLink}
\zref@newlist{UrlList}
\zref@addprops{UrlList}{UrlList@Text, UrlList@HexLink, page}
\zref@newprop{UrlList@Max}{\the\value{UrlList}}
\zref@addprops{LastPage}{UrlList@Max}

% Switch is needed in the list of URLs to disable URL recording.
\newif\ifUrlList@

% Hyperref internal is redefined to write the label with the URL data
\newcommand\saved@hyper@linkurl{}
\let\saved@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl
\renewcommand{\hyper@linkurl}[2]{%
  % #1: text
  % #2: URL
  \ifUrlList@
  \else
    \begingroup
      \refstepcounter{UrlList}%
      \protected@edef\UrlList@Text{#1}%
      \@onelevel@sanitize\UrlList@Text
      \EdefEscapeHex\UrlList@HexLink{#2}%
      \zref@labelbylist{\theUrlList}{UrlList}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \saved@hyper@linkurl{#1}{#2}%
}

% \UrlList checks, whether are URL references and prints the list of URLs
\newcommand*{\UrlList}{%
  \zref@refused{LastPage}%
  \edef\UrlList@Max{%
    \zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{UrlList@Max}{-1}%
  }%
  \ifnum\UrlList@Max<0 %
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Rerun LaTeX to get list of URLs}%
  \else
    \UrlList@true
    \begin{UrlListEnv}%
      \let\UrlList@LastPage\@empty
      \setcounter{UrlListAux}{0}%
      \@whilenum\value{UrlListAux}<\UrlList@Max\do{%
        \stepcounter{UrlListAux}%
        \zref@refused{\theUrlListAux}%
        \zref@ifrefundefined{\theUrlListAux}{%
        }{%
          \EdefUnescapeHex\UrlList@Link{%
            \zref@extract{\theUrlListAux}{UrlList@HexLink}%
          }%
          \zref@def@extract\UrlList@Text{\theUrlListAux}{UrlList@Text}%
          \zref@def@extract\UrlList@Page{\theUrlListAux}{page}%
          \edef\UrlList@Next{%
            \noexpand\UrlListItem{%
              \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\UrlList@Page}%
            }{%
              \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\UrlList@Link}%
            }{%
              \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{\UrlList@Text}%
            }%
          }%
          \ifx\UrlList@Page\UrlList@LastPage
          \else
            \expandafter\UrlListPage\expandafter{\UrlList@Page}%
            \let\UrlList@LastPage\UrlList@Page
          \fi
          \UrlList@Next
        }%
      }%
    \end{UrlListEnv}%
  \fi
}
\makeatletter

% USER configuration

% Environment UrlListEnv surrounds the list of URLs, if
% URLs are available.
\newenvironment{UrlListEnv}{%
  \begin{description}%
}{%
  \end{description}%
}

% \UrlListPage{<page>}
% Sets the page header
\newcommand*{\UrlListPage}[1]{%
  \item[\hyperlink{page.#1}{Page #1}]\mbox{}%
}

% \UrlListItem{<page>}{<URL>}{<text>}
% Formats a URL entry
\newcommand*{\UrlListItem}[3]{%
  \\\relax#3 \dots\ \href{#2}{\nolinkurl{#2}}%
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\href{http://wikipedia.org}{Wikipedia} \href{http://stackexchange.com}{SXE}  
\newpage
\href{http://google.com}{Google}

\href{http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006055121&dateTexte=20110206}{blabla}

\section*{Index of URLs}
\UrlList
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use a text width of 100cm I have no overfull. `;-)`. Seriously, this depends on the text width and on where the object is placed. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the issue?

Comment: no answers ...?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to add `\raggedright` to the definition of the `UrlListEnv` environment:

```
% Environment UrlListEnv surrounds the list of URLs, if
% URLs are available.
\newenvironment{UrlListEnv}{%
  \raggedright
  \begin{description}%
}{%
  \end{description}%
}
```

With just this change the output is

[image]

Trying to justify such long URLs is hopeless.