# latexmk doesn't seem to act on my custom dependency for makeindex

Tags: latexmk

I am trying to get a document to print a list of urls, and I have [the sample here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121986/24375) that needs me to run `makeindex` in between the invocations of pdflatex. `latexmk -pdf` doesn't seem to do it automatically, although I thought it would convert `.idx` files to `.ind` files and re-run `pdflatex` automatically.

Manually, this is how it works: I have a `main.tex` file.

```
$ pdflatex main      # produces main-url.idx and main-url.mst
$ makeindex main-url # produces main-url.ind
$ pdflatex main      # produces a pdf with the index .ind file just created
```

As I understand it, `latexmk` takes care of running `makeindex` automatically, but when I run it on a clean directory (with only `main.tex`), the `.ind` file is never created, and the index doesn't end up in the pdf.

What I have tried: First, I tried adding the following dependency to a local `latexmkrc` file, but that didn't work (I think because there is already a rule to turn `.idx` files into `.ind` files:

```
# support for the printing urls:
add_cus_dep('idx', 'ind', 0, 'makeurlindex');
sub makeurlindex {
  return system("makeindex \"$_[0].idx\"");
}
```

Then I tried changing the output extension to `.ndx` and having the custom dependency as follows, but again, no dice:

```
# support for the printing urls:
add_cus_dep('ndx', 'ind', 0, 'makeurlindex');
sub makeurlindex {
  return system("makeindex \"$_[0].ndx\"");
}
```

Additionally, I tried changing the output file to `main.idx` and updated the custom dependency accordingly, but it didn't work, either.

Finally, I tried making the dependency go from `.mst` to `.ind`, but that didn't work.

How can I make `latexmk` act on this dependency?

Comment: I think it should be just the extension without the leading dot in the first two arguments of `add_cus_dep`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks!  You are correct -- I removed the leading dot and fixed it above (and didn't have the leading dot in my own doc). Still not difference. :(

Answer (score 3):

I determined a way to use the regular `idx`->`ind` dependency handling, which was to provide a log message in the latex file:

```
\wlog{}
\wlog{Writing index file \jobname-url.idx}
```

The extra log message is to force a newline before the actual message.

This enabled the `latexmk` script to find the index message and handle it.