# Is it possible to aggregate all the hyperlinks used in a document

Tags: hyperref

I have used a lot of url links in one of my document using hyperref package. I want to aggregate all of them in a list. Is it possible to do it automatically？I can't find it anywhere in the web.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121977/82917?