# How to check if the selected letter is uppercase or lowercase in a macro?

Tags: macros, texmaker, capitalization

I'm using Texmaker and want to define some custom macros. The macros shall check if a selected letter is uppercase or lowercase and then replace that letter by a sequence defined in the macro. I need this macro to substitute turkish characters

- `\u{g}` – ğ
- `\u{G}` – Ğ
- `\c{c}` – ç
- `\c{C}` – Ç
- `\c{s}` – ş
- `\c{S}` – Ş
- `{\i}` – ı
- `\.{I}` – İ

but I don't want to manually select the uppercase or lowercase version of the character everytime. I did not find any reference to macros in the [texmaker documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html) and ixquicking *latex uppercase macro* turns up results with overly complicated scripts.

I want the macro to work like this: in the text 'Şimşek' I select the 'ş' and by pressing the hotkey assigned to my macro the letter turns into `\c{s}`. That same macro should turn 
The 'Ş' into `\c{S}` when it is selected and the hotkey is pressed.

How what I define a macro to do just that?

Comment: If you used `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you should be able just to type `Şimşek` and not need `\c` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the original text is encoded in iso-8859-1. I tried to change the input encoding to utf-8 but that gave me too many errors i did not want to have to cope with.

Answer (score 2):

I did not fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but you can check whether a string contains a letter, similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26873/21372).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}
%
\def\isuppercase#1{%
  \instring{#1}{AÂBCÇDEFGĞHIİÎJKLMNOÖÔPRSŞTUÜÛVYZ}%
}%
\makeatother

\if\isuppercase{A}YES\else NO\fi

\if\isuppercase{a}YES\else NO\fi

\end{document}
```