# Chess notation: Switch between color and notation style

Tags: conditionals, chess, chessboard, xskak, chessfss

Consider the following two examples:

**Example A**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\usetextfig
\textsymfigsymbol{R}a1 versus 
\usesymfig
\textsymfigsymbol{R}a1

\end{document}
```

[image: outputA]

Here, the notation style is changed.

**Example B**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usesymfig

\setboardfontsize{10pt}

\begin{document}

\textsymfigsymbol{Q} versus
\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\BlackQueenOnWhite}

\end{document}
```

[image: outputB]

Here, the piece color is changed.

*Addendum*

The other commands for the black pieces are

```
\BlackKingOnWhite
\BlackRookOnWhite
\BlackBishopOnWhite
\BlackKnightOnWhite
\BlackPawnOnWhite
```

**Question**

Can I somehow combine the two examples?

I would like a command where I can switch between typesetting a black or a white piece (all the different pieces!), and at the same time be able to switch between algebraic notation and figure notation globally using `\usetextfig` or `\usesymfig`.

Comment: Will you need code for more figurines or only the queen?

Comment: Yes, for all the pieces.

Comment: With \boardfont you use lower case for the black characters: {\boardfont q}.  Changing the baseline is still a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this. By using `ex` as value and setting the fontsize in the command it will work for other font sizes too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}

\usesymfig


\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\cfss@king@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.31ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackKingOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@queen@@LSBblack {\raisebox{-0.37ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackQueenOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@rook@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.26ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackRookOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@bishop@@LSBblack{\raisebox{-0.35ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackBishopOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@knight@@LSBblack{\raisebox{-0.30ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackKnightOnWhite}}
  \newcommand*\cfss@pawn@@LSBblack  {\raisebox{-0.31ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\BlackPawnOnWhite}}

\newcommand\usesymfigblack{%
 \def\cfss@figlanguage{@LSBblack}}
\makeatother 


\begin{document}

\usetextfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}
\usesymfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}
\usesymfigblack
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}


\footnotesize

\usetextfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}
\usesymfig
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}
\usesymfigblack
\textsymfigsymbol{Q}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! (Is `tikz` needed here?)

Comment: I use tikz to check the baseline (with a `\tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(0,5);` before the symbols).

Comment: Would you mind if I update your answer with some more accurate values regarding the baseline issue? (I've used `\Huge` and zoomed in to 6400 % in Adobe Reader in order to get it as precise as possible.)

Comment: Sure if you want. btw: The ex is from the text font. So it can change. It would be probably better to first select the chess font.

Comment: I think `\newcommand*\cfss@king@@LSBblack  {{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}\fontencoding{LSB}\selectfont\raisebox{-0.33ex}{\BlackKingOnWhite}}}` would be a better setting.

Comment: Hmm! Actually, to me it looks like the black king is not as tall as the white counterpart. I haven't compared the other pieces. (If I align at the bottom of the kings, I still get the best result with `-0.31ex`.)

Comment: The two board kings `\WhiteKingOnWhite` and `\BlackKingOnWhite` have the same size, but the figure king can be different.

Answer (score 1):

There's an annoying issue with the baseline. If they don't line up properly for you, change the value `-1.2pt` to an appropriate value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessfss}

\makeatletter
\def\cfssfixbaseline#1{\raise-1.2pt\hbox{#1}}
\def\useblackfig{\def\cfss@figlanguage{@BLSB}}
\def\usewhitefig{\def\cfss@figlanguage{@WLSB}}
\def\cfss@king@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteKingOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@queen@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteQueenOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@rook@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteRookOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@bishop@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteBishopOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@knight@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteKnightOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@pawn@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhitePawnOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@king@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackKingOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@queen@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackQueenOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@rook@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackRookOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@bishop@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackBishopOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@knight@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackKnightOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@pawn@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackPawnOnWhite}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textsymfigsymbol{K}
\usewhitefig
\textsymfigsymbol{K}
\useblackfig
\textsymfigsymbol{p}
\textsymfigsymbol{N}
\usewhitefig
\textsymfigsymbol{R}
\usetextfig
\textsymfigsymbol{R}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a closed command instead of constantly typing in various switch commands. 
In other words: a command that recognizes which symbol is wanted based on upper and lower case, just like you can do with board-input in `xskak.sty` or `chessboard.sty`.

So I have as a concoction of here

```
\def\FirstArgX{text}
\newcommand\skaksymb[2][]{\begingroup%
\def\SecondArgX{#1}%
\ifx\FirstArgX\SecondArgX \usetextfig\textsymfigsymbol{#2}\else%
\if\isuppercase{#2}\textsymfigsymbol{#2}%  \usewhitefig
\else%
\useblackfig\textsymfigsymbol{#2}\fi\fi%
\endgroup}
```

crafted.
(Hint: I didn't get the `\skaksymb` command to still have the same name as the old one `\textsymfigsymbol`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{chessfss}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403947/chess-notation-switch-between-color-and-notation-style
\makeatletter
\def\cfssfixbaseline#1{\raisebox{-0.31ex}{\setboardfontsize{\f@size}#1}}
\def\useblackfig{\def\cfss@figlanguage{@BLSB}}
\def\usewhitefig{\def\cfss@figlanguage{@WLSB}}
\def\cfss@king@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteKingOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@queen@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteQueenOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@rook@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteRookOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@bishop@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteBishopOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@knight@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhiteKnightOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@pawn@@WLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@WhitePawnOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@king@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackKingOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@queen@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackQueenOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@rook@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackRookOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@bishop@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackBishopOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@knight@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackKnightOnWhite}}
\def\cfss@pawn@@BLSB{\cfssfixbaseline{\cfss@BlackPawnOnWhite}}
%
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312066/46023
\def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}
%
\def\isuppercase#1{%
  \instring{#1}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ}%
}%
\makeatother

\def\FirstArgX{text}
\newcommand\skaksymb[2][]{\begingroup%
\def\SecondArgX{#1}%
\ifx\FirstArgX\SecondArgX \usetextfig\textsymfigsymbol{#2}\else%
\if\isuppercase{#2}\textsymfigsymbol{#2}%  \usewhitefig
\else%
\useblackfig\textsymfigsymbol{#2}\fi\fi%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\section{Old}
\textsymfigsymbol{K}, \textsymfigsymbol{k},
\begingroup
\usewhitefig\textsymfigsymbol{K}
\useblackfig\textsymfigsymbol{p},  
\textsymfigsymbol{N}
\usewhitefig\textsymfigsymbol{R},
\usetextfig\textsymfigsymbol{R}
\endgroup

\section{New}
\begin{tcblisting}{notitle, sidebyside, boxrule=0.4pt}
\skaksymb{K}, 
\skaksymb{k},
\skaksymb[text]{K}
\end{tcblisting}


\section{In Text}
ABC\skaksymb{K}abc\skaksymb{k}, \skaksymb[text]{k}

{\Huge ABC\skaksymb{K}abc\skaksymb{k}, \skaksymb[text]{k}   }

{\footnotesize ABC\skaksymb{K}abc\skaksymb{k}, \skaksymb[text]{k}}

\section{In chess-annotation}
\newchessgame[id=MyGame] 
\hidemoves{1.e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6
3. Bb5 Nf6 4. O-O Nxe4 5.Bxc6 bxc6
6. Kh1 Rg8
}
%\printchessgame[id=MyGame, style=styleCx]

\xskaknewstyleitem[%
template=UF,% a predefined style item
beforewhite={\usewhitefig},
beforeblack={\useblackfig},
afterblack=\color{black}\hspace{1.25ex}
]{myitems}

\xskakaddtostyle[%
font=\normalfont,% <--- he wants something here....
styleitem=myitems
]{test}
%\printchessgame[id=MyGame, style=test]

\begin{tcbitemize}[sharp corners, raster equal height=rows,
colback=white,
raster column skip=0mm,
boxrule=1.2pt, boxsep=1ex, 
]
\tcbitem[left=0pt] \chessboard[]
\tcbitem[] \printchessgame[id=MyGame, style=test]
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```