# Coloring References

Tags: bibtex

Possible duplicate [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305085/coloring-more-than-one-references-in-bibtex?noredirect=1&lq=1)
My requirements are as follows:

- I use a separate .bib file that contains all the entries.
- I use `\cite{CiteKey1,CiteKey2,CiteKey3}`. I want to highlight `\citecolor{CiteKey2}` in different color (say blue) in the reference section. I don't know how to define `\citecolor`.
- I want to highlight for several references.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}  
\usepackage{xcolor,cite}
\begin{document}
 I use~\cite{CiteKey1,CiteKey2,CiteKey3}`. I want to highlight~\citecolor{CiteKey2}` in different color (say blue) in the reference section.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{MBibliography}
\end{document}
```

MBibliography.bib contains

```
@ARTICLE{CiteKey1, 
author={Author 1}, 
journal={Journal Name1}, 
title={Title}, 
year={2010},
}

@ARTICLE{CiteKey2, 
author={Author 2}, 
journal={Journal Name2}, 
title={Title}, 
year={2010},
}

@ARTICLE{CiteKey3, 
author={Author3}, 
journal={Journal Name3}, 
title={Title}, 
year={2010},
}
```

[image]

Comment: Er ... why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @cfr I want to highlight some reference while making it easier to reply reviewers' comments.

Comment: Similar question for `natbib`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224596/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-natbib

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes good. It's an another approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With biblatex it would be easier ... but you can try it like this

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xcolor,cite,etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\pretocmd\@bibitem{\color{black}\csname keycolor#1\endcsname}{}{\fail}
\newcommand\citecolor[1]{\@namedef{keycolor#1}{\color{blue}}}
\makeatother
\citecolor{CiteKey2}
\begin{document}
I use~\cite{CiteKey1,CiteKey2,CiteKey3}`. I want to highlight in different color (say blue) in the reference section.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]