# Coloring four or five specific references in Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, color

Please look at the question and the answer given in this link for coloring references[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305085/coloring-more-than-one-references-in-bibtex?noredirect=1&lq=1)
It works with two references. How can it be edited for four or five references?

Here is a copy of the solution. But I am not able to add more nested ifstrequal:

```
 \let\mybibitem\bibitem
 \renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
 \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey1>}
    {\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}% IF #1==<BibtexKey1>
  \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey2>}
    {\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}% IF #1==<BibtexKey1>
  {% ELSE
  \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey3>}
    {\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}% IF #1==<BibtexKey1>
    {\color{black}\mybibitem{#1}}% ELSE
  }%
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I am not able to add more nested `\ifstrequal`". Are you getting error or warning messages (and, if so, what do the messages say?), or are you not sure how to carry out the additional nesting steps?

Comment: @Mico. Actually the code above works very well with 2 references. However, when I tried to color 3 references, I copy and paste 
\ifstrequal{#1} with changing the bibtex Key. However, it does not work. My question is how to color more than 2 refeences.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: "What exactly does "it does not work" entail?"

Comment: I updated the code above. Simply, what I did to get "BibtexKey2" colored like BibtexKey1 and BibtexKey3. I just want to Syntax that I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting multiple `\ifstrequal` as follows shouldn't be an issue.

The basic syntax is

```
\let\mybibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey1>}%
    {%
        % what happens if you key == <BibtexKey1>
    }%
    {%
        % what happens if it's another key
        % this is where you want to define your next `\ifstrequal` statement.
    }%
}
```

Thus, you get for highlighting both `<BibtexKey1>` and `<BibtexKey2>`, this gives:

```
\let\mybibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey1>}%
    {%
        % what happens if you key == <BibtexKey1>
        \color{red}\mybibitem{#1}%
    }%
    {%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey2>}%
        {%
            % what happens if you key == <BibtexKey2>
            \color{red}\mybibitem{#1}%
        }%
        {%
            % what happens if it's another key
            \color{black}\mybibitem{#1}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

If you want to highlight `<BibtexKey3>` as well, this gives:

```
\let\mybibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey1>}%
    {%
        % what happens if you key == <BibtexKey1>
        \color{red}\mybibitem{#1}%
    }%
    {%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey2>}%
        {%
            % what happens if you key == <BibtexKey2>
            \color{red}\mybibitem{#1}%
        }%
        {%
            \ifstrequal{#1}{<BibtexKey3>}%
            {%
                % what happens if you key == <BibtexKey3>
                \color{red}\mybibitem{#1}%
            }%
            {%
                % what happens if it is another key
                \color{black}\mybibitem{#1}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
```

Et cætera.

This works as a quick solution — yet it is dirty indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Nesting multiple `\ifstrequal` is a pain. Here's a way with `expl3` that avoids nesting.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setupbibcolors}{m}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Npn \bibitem ##1
   {
    \color{ \str_case:nnF { ##1 } { #1 } { black } }
    \heba_bibitem:n { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_set_eq:NN \heba_bibitem:n \bibitem

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setupbibcolors{
  {Pinter2019}{green!70!red}
  {JainAndWallace2019}{red!60}
  {SurveyOfAttentionModels}{yellow!40!black}
  {Vig2019}{blue!40}
  {TransformerXL}{cyan!60!yellow}
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{chico}

\end{document}
```

You can set up as many entries as you want and the colors need not be different.

Due to laziness, the bib file is taken from another answer of mine, see [BibTex error that I can't solve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525660/bibtex-error-that-i-cant-solve)

[image]