# Coloring Specific References in Bibliography

Tags: macros, bibliographies, color

In revised versions of a manuscript, we usually mark the new changes with colored text. This question is concerned about the different ways that this can be done for specific references in the `.bib` file. There are previous solutions about this but they are not satisfactory to me. [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242042/how-to-change-text-color-a-particular-reference-in-the-bibliography-in-latex-u) just do the job for one reference. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305085/coloring-more-than-one-references-in-bibtex?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the extension of the previous one for several references by using several nested `ifstreqal`. But this can get really useless when the number of colored references increases.

What I have in mind is to have a code, which gets all of the labels of colored references without getting the user involved in making nested structures.

Other new solutions are also welcomed.

Here is a MWE to start with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
    @article{greenwade93,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
        volume  = "14",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "342--351"
    }
    @book{goossens93,
        author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
        title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
        year      = "1993",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
    }
    @article{fuente, 
        author = "D. de la Fuente and J.G. Castaño and M. Morcillo", 
        title = "Long-term atmospheric corrosion of zinc", 
        journal = "Corrosion Science", 
        volume = "49", 
        year = "2007", 
        pages = "1420–1436",
    }
    @article{nature, 
        author = "Rosa Rademakers and Manuela Neumann and Ian R. Mackenzie", 
        title = "Advances in understanding the molecular basis of frontotemporal dementia - elongated title", 
        journal = "Nature Reviews Neurology", 
        volume = "8", 
        year = "2012", 
        pages = "423-434", 
        doi = "10.1038/nrneurol.2012.117",
    } 
} 
\end{filecontents}

\let\mybibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{greenwade93}
    {\color{blue}\mybibitem{#1}}
    {\color{black}\mybibitem{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

This is my document \cite{fuente} and we have another \cite{nature}. We can speak also about \LaTeX! So two more reference are \cite{greenwade93} and \cite{goossens93}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you switch to biblatex? There you could define a category and add your references to it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That would be no problem if it is similar to bibTeX from a user point of view. :) I would like to know your solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

With biblatex/biber it is rather easy to mark references:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{changed}
\addtocategory{changed}{doody,angenendt}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifcategory{changed}{\color{red}}{}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\ifcategory{changed}{\textcolor{green}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\cite{doody,herrmann,angenendt}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Thanks for your answer. Would you please edit the answer such that there are four references from which two or three are colored. :)

Comment: You only need to add more keys to the \addtocategory.