# How to color a specific reference in bibliography using apacite?

Tags: bibliographies, color, apa6, apacite

I would like to color in red specific citations in bibliography section (let's say Jahani et al.) using the `apa6` class and the `apacite` package.

Here is my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,noextraspace,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title of the Study}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

I want to color \citeA{jahani2018motion} in red in bibliography section. However, I want \citeA{drenckhahn2015validation} and \citeA{magistretti1999energy} to remain in black.

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And here is my `.bib` file:

```
@article{drenckhahn2015validation,
  title={A validation study of the use of near-infrared spectroscopy imaging in primary and secondary motor areas of the human brain},
  author={Drenckhahn, Christoph and Koch, Stefan P and D{\"u}mmler, Johannes and Kohl-Bareis, Matthias and Steinbrink, Jens and Dreier, Jens P},
  journal={Epilepsy \& Behavior},
  doi={10.1016/j.yebeh.2015.04.006},
  volume={49},
  pages={118--125},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{jahani2018motion,
  title={Motion artifact detection and correction in functional near-infrared spectroscopy: {A} new hybrid method based on spline interpolation method and {S}avitzky--{G}olay filtering},
  author={Jahani, Sahar and Setarehdan, Seyed K and Boas, David A and Y{\"u}cel, Meryem A},
  journal={Neurophotonics},
  doi={10.1117/1.NPh.5.1.015003},
  volume={5},
  number={1},
  pages={1--11},
  year={2018},
  publisher={International Society for Optics and Photonics}
}

@article{magistretti1999energy,
  title={Energy on demand},
  author={Magistretti, Pierre J and Pellerin, Luc and Rothman, Douglas L and Shulman, Robert G},
  journal={Science},
  doi={10.1126/science.283.5401.496},
  volume={283},
  pages={496--497},
  year={1999},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327357/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242042/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414758/35864,

Comment: Thank you @moewe, I saw them, but the suggested solutions do not work for apacite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327845/35864) to [Coloring References](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327357/35864), but extending it to items with an explicit label we get

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,noextraspace,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\@bibitem{\color{black}\csname keycolor#1\endcsname}{}{\fail}
\apptocmd\@lbibitem{\color{black}\csname keycolor#2\endcsname}{}{\fail}
\newcommand\citecolor[2][red]{\@namedef{keycolor#2}{\color{#1}}}
\makeatother

\citecolor[blue]{jahani2018motion}

\shorttitle{Study}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{drenckhahn2015validation,
  title   = {A validation study of the use of near-infrared spectroscopy
             imaging in primary and secondary motor areas of the human brain},
  author  = {Drenckhahn, Christoph and Koch, Stefan P. and D{\"u}mmler, Johanne
             and Kohl-Bareis, Matthias and Steinbrink, Jens and Dreier, Jens P.},
  journal = {Epilepsy \& Behavior},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.yebeh.2015.04.006},
  volume  = {49},
  pages   = {118--125},
  year    = {2015},
}
@article{jahani2018motion,
  title   = {Motion artifact detection and correction in functional
             near-infrared spectroscopy:
             {A} new hybrid method based on spline interpolation method
             and {S}avitzky--{G}olay filtering},
  author  = {Jahani, Sahar and Setarehdan, Seyed K. and Boas, David A.
             and Y{\"u}cel, Meryem A.},
  journal = {Neurophotonics},
  doi     = {10.1117/1.NPh.5.1.015003},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1--11},
  year    = {2018},
}
@article{magistretti1999energy,
  title   = {Energy on demand},
  author  = {Magistretti, Pierre J. and Pellerin, Luc and Rothman, Douglas L.
             and Shulman, Robert G.},
  journal = {Science},
  doi     = {10.1126/science.283.5401.496},
  volume  = {283},
  pages   = {496--497},
  year    = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
I want to color \citeA{jahani2018motion} in red in bibliography section
However, I want \citeA{drenckhahn2015validation}
and \citeA{magistretti1999energy} to remain in black.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: References with <code>jahani2018motion</code> highlighted in blue.]

`\citecolor` can be issued anywhere before `\bibliography`. The command has two arguments. The optional (first) argument is the colour, the mandatory (second) argument the key of the entry to be highlighted.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly!!!!