# Labelling list of points in PGF scatter plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following input file (sample.txt):

```
A 1 2
B 23 2
C 2 34
D 12 22
E 23 3
F 34 12
```

I want to create a scatter plot where the second column is the x-axis, the third column is the y-axis, and the first column is the label for each point.

However, I want to **only** label points that exist in a list L = [B,D,E]

The list which should be defined in the source code (i.e. not in a file), can be changed and should reflect in the plot.

I'm having a difficult time getting this done in PGF plots. Any ideas?

Here's my attempt so far

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [mark = x, 
        only marks,
        visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{0}}
    ] table[x index = 1, y index = 2] {annot_no_align.out};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: as you can probably tell, I'm a beginner in PGFPlots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is a combination of `node near coords` and some `if`-exercise.

one can find the definition of `\pgfutil@in@` in `pgfutil-common.tex`. Also one can look up LaTeX's `\includeonly` and BEAMER's `\includeonlyframes`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\labelonly{BDF}
\def\labelcheck#1{
    \edef\pgfmarshal{\noexpand\pgfutil@in@{#1}{\labelonly}}
    \pgfmarshal
    \ifpgfutil@in@[#1]\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[
        mark=*,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords={
            \labelcheck{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        }
    ]
        table[header=false,meta index=0,x index=1,y index=2]{
            A 1 2
            B 23 2
            C 2 34
            D 12 22
            E 23 3
            F 34 12
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter

\end{document}
```

## Update

[image]

Here is a better solution when you prefer CSV. I am using native `\pgfkeys` features so you probably already know what is dangerous and what is not. (e.g. comma is dangerous.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /prepare label/.style={
        /print label/\detokenize{#1}/.code={\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}
    },
    /prepare label/.list={^_^,@_@,T_T}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[
        mark=*,
        only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords={
            \pgfkeys{/print label/\pgfplotspointmeta/.try}
        }
    ]
        table[header=false,meta index=0,x index=1,y index=2]{
            ^_^   1  2
            >_<  23  2
            @_@   2 34
            Q_Q  23  3
            T_T  12 22
            =_=  34 12
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This might help as well http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/check-if-a-string-contains-a-given-character.

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know about pgfutil-common.tex. It'll take me a while to fully understand how your code works, but it seems to do what I want. I do have one final question: is it easy to support labels made up of several characters (including underscores)? i.e. instead of "A","B","C",...,"F", I'd like to have "First_Label", "Second_Label", ...

Comment: @alguru That is the reason why I mentioned `\includeonly`. This command *eat* a list of filenames and then whenever you issue a `\inclulde{filename}` it checks if the `filename` is in the list.

Comment: @alguru place check out the update.

Comment: Haha very nice !

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks that's just what I needed. I wouldn't have figured out in a million years.

Comment: Why in your first plot points A, C, E are not marked ? Is it possible to mark all the points? On a related note, when I add an extra column to the table and properly select columns, all markings disappear. Any idea why this can happen?

Comment: @yarchik because `\def\labelonly{BDF}` defines the labels that will be shown. Would you like to ask a new question with a handy MWE, so potentially there are more people can help? (Also, [tag:pgfplots] is now `1.15` so something might be obsolete.