# tikzpicture plot error message

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a plot with only a few points. But I get a lot of error messages like `Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}`

Can somebody explain me what is wrong in my code.

```
\documentclass[
12pt, % font size
a4paper, % paper format
oneside, % one-sided pages
]{article}

% Graph
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Tragweite,
    ylabel=Wahrscheinlichkeit,
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
    xmax=11,
    ymax=11
    ]
    \addplot[
    mark=*,
    only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords={
        \labelcheck{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    }
    ] table[meta=label] {
        x   y   label
        3   6   1
        5   6   2
        6   4   3
        2   8   4
        1   9   5
        3   5   6
        7   3   7
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Risiken}
    \label{fig:risiken}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\labelcheck` is not a standard macro, its definition is missing. Presumably you got it from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331784/labelling-list-of-points-in-pgf-scatter-plot/332024#332024?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes I got it from there, I added the definition now, but now it does no longer show any labels.

Comment: No, the purpose of that macro is to show only a select set of labels, as defined by the `\labelonly` macro. (That is the point of the question, after all.) If you want all points labeled, just remove `={\labelcheck{\pgfplotspointmeta}}`

Comment: I can add an answer, but before I do, please specify exactly what kind of output you expect.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think I just remove the `labelcheck` then it should work and the result is sufficient enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The only uncommon thing in your code is the `\labelcheck` macro. This is not part of `pgfplots`, but defined by Symbol 1 in his answer to [Labelling list of points in PGF scatter plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331784/labelling-list-of-points-in-pgf-scatter-plot/332024#332024). So if you add the definition of `\labelcheck` (and `\labelonly`) from that answer your code works fine.

Now, the whole point of that macro is to only print the `node near coord` for specific labels (meta values), as defined by the `\labelonly` macro. Note in that code that the `meta` values are A through F, and that with `\labelonly{BDF}` only those three labels are shown. You have `meta` values 1 through 7, so with `\labelonly{BDF}` nothing is of course printed. Modify it to `\labelonly{236}` and those labels are printed.

As I understand it though, you want all the labels to be printed, so all of that stuff is unnecessary -- printing all the labels is the default. Hence, all you need to do is remove `={\labelcheck{\pgpflotspointmeta}}`, and then you can remove the definition of `\labelcheck` as well.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[
12pt, % font size
a4paper, % paper format
oneside, % one-sided pages
]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Tragweite,
    ylabel=Wahrscheinlichkeit,
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
    xmax=11,
    ymax=11
    ]
    \addplot[
    mark=*,
    only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords % removed the \labelcheck stuff
    ] table[meta=label] {
        x   y   label
        3   6   1
        5   6   2
        6   4   3
        2   8   4
        1   9   5
        3   5   6
        7   3   7
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Risiken}
    \label{fig:risiken}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```