# Bold name in bib when having a prefix in last name

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using the template from here: https://www.overleaf.com/16456399bnxqhtkjwzft#/63153901/

I am trying to make my name bold in the publications list by setting in the `.tex` file:

```
\myname{de\bibnamedelima Klein}{Niek}
```

and in the `.sty` file

```
\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
   \def\@mylastname{#1}%
   \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
}


\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}
```

and in the `.bib` file my name is written as:

```
de Klein, Niek
```

However, because I have two parts in my last name, it is not making it bold. When I change my name to `Klein, Niek` in the bib file and `\myname{Klein}{Niek}` in the tex file, or when I change my name to `Klein, Niek de` in the bib file and `\myname{Klein}{Niek\bibnamedelima de}` in the tex file it does correctly bold my name.

So the two part name does work if I put it as two first names, but not when I put it as two lasts names.

---

Compilable snippets:

`cv.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}
\usepackage{settings}
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}
\myname{de\bibnamedelima Klein}{Niek}
\excludecomment{fullonly}
\begin{document}
\input{publications}
\end{document}
```

`settings.sty`

```
\RequirePackage[main=british]{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage{fontawesome}



\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line.
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=apa,sorting=ydnt,uniquename=init,maxnames=7,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}

\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}
% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2.7em}
\NewBibliographyString{retrieved}
\NewBibliographyString{from}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
  from = {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\faLink}},
  retrieved = {}
}

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=black!40!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
   \def\@mylastname{#1}%
   \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
}


\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

`own-bib.bib`

```
@article{example},
  title={Some titel},
  author={de Klein, Niek and Other, Authors},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={5},
  pages={470},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `biblatex`'s field annotation facilities for the purpose. With them, you should indicate the annotation in the bib file with something like `author+an = {1=mynamebold},` (`1` refers to the first author of the list, `mynamebold` is the annotations name).

An then, you can redefine the name part macros to make the name bold conditionally on the presence of the annotation.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
  title={Some titel},
  author={de Klein, Niek and Other, Authors},
  author+an = {1=mynamebold},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={5},
  pages={470},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{mynamebold}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{mynamebold}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{mynamebold}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as `biblatex` is concerned, your family/last name is not *de Klein*, it is *Klein* when you input your name as `author = {de Klein, Niek}`. The *de* is treated as prefix/von part. Classical BibTeX knows four name parts (the term before the slash is `biblatex`'s name see also [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864), the term after the slash is BibTeX's name)

1. Family/last name, here *Klein*
2. Given/first name, here *Niek*
3. Prefix/von part, here *de*
4. Suffix/junior part, here `<empty>`

A name in the `.bib` file is parsed with certain rules to split it up into these four components. See [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864)

The name prefix is not treated as a rigid part of the family name because the traditions in some countries treat the name prefix differently. In German texts for example it might happen that prefixes like 'von', 'van', ... are treated and shown like an additional first name for sorting purposes (*Beethoven, Ludwig van*) or the prefix is displayed with the family name but ignored for sorting purposes (*van Beethoven, Ludwig* sorts under *B*). This is easier if the prefix is considered a part of its own.

This means that if you try `\myname{Klein}{Niek}` depending on the output format you could get

> de **Klein**, Niek
>
> **Niek**, **Klein** de
>
> **Niek** de **Klein**

None of the above options are exactly what you want because the *de* is never in bold which looks absolutely weird in the third example and visually splits the *de* from your name in the other two examples. Additionally, someone called *Niek Klein* (without the *de*) would also be highlighted.

I suggest you find a different solution for bold names from [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864). My favourite solution is presented in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\hlblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -boldnames.bib}
\newwrite\hlblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\hlblx@bibfile=\hlblx@bibfile@name

\newcounter{hlblx@name}
\setcounter{hlblx@name}{0}

\newcommand*{\hlblx@writenametobib}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{hlblx@name}%
  \edef\hlblx@tmp@nocite{%
    \noexpand\AfterPreamble{%
      \noexpand\setbox0\noexpand\vbox{%
        \noexpand\hlblx@getmethehash{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name}}}}%
  }%
  \hlblx@tmp@nocite
  \immediate\write\hlblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name}, author = {\unexpanded{#1}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\hlblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\hlblx@bibfile@name}

\newcommand*{\hlbxl@boldhashes}{}
\DeclareNameFormat{hlblx@hashextract}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\hlbxl@boldhashes}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\hlbxl@boldhashes}{\thefield{fullhash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\hlblx@getmethehash}
  {}
  {\printnames[hlblx@hashextract][1-999]{author}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand*{\addboldnames}{\forcsvlist\hlblx@writenametobib}
\newcommand*{\resetboldnames}{\def\hlbxl@boldhashes{}}

\newcommand*{\mkboldifhashinlist}[1]{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\hlbxl@boldhashes}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{boldifhashinlist}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkboldifhashinlist}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{boldifhashinlist}

\addboldnames{Niek de Klein}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
  title     = {Some titel},
  author    = {de Klein, Niek and Other, Authors},
  journal   = {Journal},
  volume    = {5},
  pages     = {470},
  year      = {2015},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It uses a bit of machinery to allow you to input your name exactly as you would type it in a `.bib` file. The answer is based on a version of [Audrey's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/35864) using hashes. Audrey's answer itself unfortunately does not take name prefixes into account for name comparisons, so both Niek de Klein and Niek Klein would be highlighted.

*edited* to use a more elegant version to format complete names. `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat` and `\mkbibcompletename` are only available in `biblatex` v3.12 (2018-10-30) and v3.13 (2019-08-17), respectively. Please refer to the edit history if you are using an older version of `biblatex`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while using the Europass CV template from Overleaf. While I guess that @moewe answer might have worked for me, I could not really understand it and found it too complex for me, and thus I tried to find my own way. I ended up re-writing parts of the style file europasscv-bibliography.sty as my own version (europasscv-bibliography_own.sty) as follows:

```
% Note the new package name
\ProvidesPackage{europasscv-bibliography_own}
  [Additional macros for bibliography support in europasscv]

\RequirePackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\RequirePackage{longtable}

\newrobustcmd*{\defecvbibtabulartwocolumn}[5]{%
  \long\csdef{extblxtab@env@#1}{#2}%
  \long\csdef{extblxtab@endenv@#1}{#3}%
  \long\csdef{extblxtab@tabrow@format@#1}{%
    \if@ecvdebug\cellcolor{yellow!25}\fi\anchorlang{#4} & \if@ecvdebug\cellcolor{blue!25}\fi \driver{#5}\\
  }%
}

\defecvbibtabulartwocolumn{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{\medskipamount}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{\medskipamount}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{longtable}[t]{@{}R{\ecv@leftcolwidth}@{\hspace{\ecv@colsep}}p{\ecv@rightcolwidth}@{}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\selectecvfont\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}%
   \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}{\selectecvfont}

% My own new definitions start here

% the original command had only 3 entries, without the prefix name

\newcommand*{\ecvbibhighlight}[4]{%
  \def\prefname{#1}%
  \def\lastname{#2}%
  \def\firstname{#3}%
  \def\firstinit{#4}}
\ecvbibhighlight{}{}{}{}

\def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}

% usage:
% \if\instring{a}{abcdef}\message{YES}\else\message{NO}\fi

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \if\instring{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}%
  {%
    \if\instring{\firstname}{\namepartgiven}%
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}%
    \else%
    {%
      \if\instring{\firstinit}{\namepartgiven}%
      {\mkbibbold{#1}}%
      \fi%
    }%
    \fi%
  }%
  \else%
  {#1}%
  \fi%
}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \if\instring{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}%
  {%
    \if\instring{\firstname}{\namepartgiven}%
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}%
    \else%
    {%
      \if\instring{\firstinit}{\namepartgiven}%
      {\mkbibbold{#1}}%
      \fi%
    }%
    \fi%
  }%
  \else%
  {#1}%
  \fi%
}



\endinput
```

The first part is specific for the Europass format to define a new tabular-like environment, and I did not change anything there. The second part is about highlighting in bold the chosen author having a family name constituted by two words.

Then, in the main text, I called the new package:

`\usepackage{europasscv-bibliography_own}`

and I used the new definition of bold highlight:

`\ecvbibhighlight{De}{Vico}{Luca}{L.}`

And everything worked, without having to re-format the bibliography file.

The `\instring` definition was taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/check-if-a-string-contains-a-given-character)