# Bold names of some authors with prefixes

Tags: biblatex

There is a nice solution for making the names of several authors bold in the bibiliography: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355317
However, this removes the prefixes ("de", "von", etc) of the author names. How to make author names bold while keeping the prefixes?

Comment: The linked code has other issues as well (no proper support for "et al.", a syntax error in the last `\ifthenelse`). I suggest you have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433561/35864

Comment: great, thanks for the suggestion, it works perfectly

Comment: I guess this can be closed as a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: Yes, I upvoted your answer there. My apologies for not having found your answer by myself.

Comment: Please don't apologise for not finding the question. It is not always easy to locate the right questions and answers on this site, especially for common questions like this. I only found it so quickly because I edited it this morning and so it was still in my memory. Otherwise it would have taken me much longer to find a good duplicate.