# How to make an array of tokens?

Tags: conditionals

I'm trying to code a function with the help of some characters in Devanagari script. I've replaced the characters with some other characters of a totally different script. This is the MWE to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003} %Any Devanagari font.
\newfontfamily{\doulo}{Doulos SIL}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\क=\active
\protected\def क{\doulo k}
\catcode`\ख=\active
\protected\def ख{\doulo kʰ}
\catcode`\ड=\active
\protected\def ड{\doulo ɖ}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    कखड
\end{document}
```

Doulos SIL font is necessary for the characters to appear and can be obtained from [here](https://www.1001fonts.com/doulos-sil-font.html)

This produces the following -

[image: 1]

Now I want 'ə' this character to be added conditionally. It should only be added when another diacritic of Devanagari i.e. **'्'** is ***absent***. (Which in a way means whenever **'्'** comes 'ə' symbol should not be added and for every character which is not followed by the same 'ə' should be added.) For this conditional setting, I've coded this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003} %Any Devanagari font.
\newfontfamily{\doulo}{Doulos SIL}    
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\क=\active
\protected\def क{\bgroup\doulo k\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ख=\active
\protected\def ख{\bgroup\doulo kʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ड=\active
\protected\def ड{\bgroup\doulo ɖ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\protected\def\viramacheck{\ifx\tmp ्\egroup\expandafter\@gobble\else ə\egroup\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    क ख ड\\
    क् ख् ड्
\end{document}
```

This provides -

[image: 2]

This much is clear to me. Now what I wanted to know is, instead of having one conditional antecedent i.e. **'्'** I want to have an array of antecedents.

eg. To put it into a logical language, if x is followed by **्** **and** 'a' **and** 'b' **and** 'c' do not add 'ə'

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003} %Any Devanagari font.
\newfontfamily{\doulo}{Doulos SIL}    
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\क=\active
\protected\def क{\bgroup\doulo k\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ख=\active
\protected\def ख{\bgroup\doulo kʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ड=\active
\protected\def ड{\bgroup\doulo ɖ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\protected\def\viramacheck{\ifx\tmp ्\egroup\expandafter\@gobble\else ə\egroup\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    कaखbडc
\end{document}
```

The output is -

[image: 3]

and what I want is -

[image: 4]

How to make an array of these conditionals i.e. **'्'**, 'a', 'b' & 'c'?

As suggested by @siracusa I've edited the code in the following way. This is the final and fully ready code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003} %Any Devanagari font.
\newfontfamily{\doulo}{Doulos SIL}    
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\makeatletter
\def\ifischar#1{%
    \ifx\tmp#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\catcode`\क=\active
\protected\def क{\bgroup\doulo k\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ख=\active
\protected\def ख{\bgroup\doulo kʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ड=\active
\protected\def ड{\bgroup\doulo ɖ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\अ=\active
\protected\def अ{\bgroup\doulo ə}
\catcode`\ा=\active
\protected\def ा{\doulo a}
\catcode`\आ=\active
\protected\def आ{\doulo a}
\catcode`\ि=\active
\protected\def ि{\doulo i}
\catcode`\इ=\active
\protected\def इ{\doulo i}
\catcode`\ी=\active
\protected\def ी{\doulo iː}
\catcode`\ई=\active
\protected\def ई{\doulo iː}
\catcode`\ु=\active
\protected\def ु{\doulo u}
\catcode`\उ=\active
\protected\def उ{\doulo u}
\catcode`\ू=\active
\protected\def ू{\doulo uː}
\catcode`\ऊ=\active
\protected\def ऊ{\doulo uː}
\catcode`\े=\active
\protected\def े{\doulo e}
\catcode`\ए=\active
\protected\def ए{\doulo e}
\catcode`\ै=\active
\protected\def ै{\doulo ə͡i}
\catcode`\ऐ=\active
\protected\def ऐ{\doulo ə͡i}
\catcode`\ो=\active
\protected\def ो{\doulo o}
\catcode`\ओ=\active
\protected\def ओ{\doulo o}
\catcode`\ौ=\active
\protected\def ौ{\doulo ə͡u}
\catcode`\औ=\active
\protected\def औ{\doulo ə͡u}
\catcode`\ं=\active
\protected\def ं{\doulo ũ}
\protected\def\viramacheck{%
    \ifischar{्}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
        \ifischar{ा}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
            \ifischar{ी}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                \ifischar{ू}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                    \ifischar{ि}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                        \ifischar{ु}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                            \ifischar{े}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                \ifischar{ै}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                    \ifischar{ो}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                        \ifischar{ौ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                            \ifischar{अ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                \ifischar{आ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                    \ifischar{ई}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                        \ifischar{ई}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                            \ifischar{उ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                                \ifischar{ऊ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                                    \ifischar{ए}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                                        \ifischar{ऐ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                                            \ifischar{ओ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                                                \ifischar{औ}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
                                                                                    ə\egroup
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    काखीडूअए
\end{document}
```

The output -

[image: 6]

This solved the problem of adding character 'ə', but if we look at line number 23, 31 & 39  ा,   ी  &  ू are defined as **a**, **iː** & **uː** respectively. They are not coming in the output. On the contrary if we look at line number 21 & 45 अ & ए are defined as ə & e respectively and they are coming in the output. Probably there is something wrong with the diacritics. Can we solve this?

Comment: You could nest several `\ifx` tests to check for different characters. See also [Check if a string contains a given character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26870/check-if-a-string-contains-a-given-character)

Comment: You mean to say I'll have to add \protected\def\viramacheck{\ifx\tmp a\egroup\expandafter\@gobble\else ə\egroup\fi}?

Comment: but I tried doing this and then the previous definition does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by your last paragraph? How are a, i: and u: related to the input? If you want a lot of different, multi-character replacements, the `l3regex` engine may be a better option.

Comment: ा,  ी &  ू are the characters which are defined as a, i: and u: In the input I've used काखीडू which are composed of क + ा, ख + ी, ड + ू

Comment: I've noticed that diacritics on their own follow the definition, but when combined with other characters, they do not follow the same.

Comment: I think the problem is that you gobble these diacritic characters away. For example, the line `\ifischar{ा}{\egroup\@gobble}{%` shouldn't have the `\@gobble` in it because you actually want your next (active) character to be exectuted. Something with the group nesting also seems to be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96073/discussion-between-niranjan-and-siracusa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@siracusa suggested the right way of formatting my code and now I've this, which is fully ready.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003} %Any Devanagari font.
\newfontfamily{\doulo}{Doulos SIL}    
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\makeatletter
\def\ifischar#1{%
    \ifx\tmp#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\catcode`\क=\active
\protected\def क{\bgroup\doulo k\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ख=\active
\protected\def ख{\bgroup\doulo kʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ग=\active
\protected\def ग{\bgroup\doulo g\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\घ=\active
\protected\def घ{\bgroup\doulo gʱ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ङ=\active
\protected\def ङ{\bgroup\doulo ŋ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\च=\active
\protected\def च{\bgroup\doulo ʧ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\छ=\active
\protected\def छ{\bgroup\doulo ʧʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ज=\active
\protected\def ज{\bgroup\doulo ʤ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\झ=\active
\protected\def झ{\bgroup\doulo ʤʱ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ञ=\active
\protected\def ञ{\bgroup\doulo ɲ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ट=\active
\protected\def ट{\bgroup\doulo ʈ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ठ=\active
\protected\def ठ{\bgroup\doulo ʈʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ड=\active
\protected\def ड{\bgroup\doulo ɖ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ढ=\active
\protected\def ढ{\bgroup\doulo ɖʱ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ण=\active
\protected\def ण{\bgroup\doulo ɳ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\त=\active
\protected\def त{\bgroup\doulo t̪\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\थ=\active
\protected\def थ{\bgroup\doulo t̪ʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\द=\active
\protected\def द{\bgroup\doulo d̪\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ध=\active
\protected\def ध{\bgroup\doulo d̪ʱ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\न=\active
\protected\def न{\bgroup\doulo n̪\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\प=\active
\protected\def प{\bgroup\doulo p\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\फ=\active
\protected\def फ{\bgroup\doulo pʰ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ब=\active
\protected\def ब{\bgroup\doulo b\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\भ=\active
\protected\def भ{\bgroup\doulo bʱ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\म=\active
\protected\def म{\bgroup\doulo m\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\य=\active
\protected\def य{\bgroup\doulo j\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\र=\active
\protected\def र{\bgroup\doulo ɾ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ऱ=\active
\protected\def ऱ{\bgroup\doulo ɾ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ल=\active
\protected\def ल{\bgroup\doulo l\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\व=\active
\protected\def व{\bgroup\doulo w\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\श=\active
\protected\def श{\bgroup\doulo ʃ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ष=\active
\protected\def ष{\bgroup\doulo ʂ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\स=\active
\protected\def स{\bgroup\doulo s\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ह=\active
\protected\def ह{\bgroup\doulo h\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\ळ=\active
\protected\def ळ{\bgroup\doulo ɭ\futurelet\tmp\viramacheck}
\catcode`\अ=\active
\protected\def अ{\bgroup\doulo ə}
\catcode`\ा=\active
\protected\def ा{\doulo a}
\catcode`\आ=\active
\protected\def आ{\doulo a}
\catcode`\ि=\active
\protected\def ि{\doulo i}
\catcode`\इ=\active
\protected\def इ{\doulo i}
\catcode`\ी=\active
\protected\def ी{\doulo iː}
\catcode`\ई=\active
\protected\def ई{\doulo iː}
\catcode`\ु=\active
\protected\def ु{\doulo u}
\catcode`\उ=\active
\protected\def उ{\doulo u}
\catcode`\ू=\active
\protected\def ू{\doulo uː}
\catcode`\ऊ=\active
\protected\def ऊ{\doulo uː}
\catcode`\े=\active
\protected\def े{\doulo e}
\catcode`\ए=\active
\protected\def ए{\doulo e}
\catcode`\ै=\active
\protected\def ै{\doulo ə͡i}
\catcode`\ऐ=\active
\protected\def ऐ{\doulo ə͡i}
\catcode`\ो=\active
\protected\def ो{\doulo o}
\catcode`\ओ=\active
\protected\def ओ{\doulo o}
\catcode`\ौ=\active
\protected\def ौ{\doulo ə͡u}
\catcode`\औ=\active
\protected\def औ{\doulo ə͡u}
\catcode`\ं=\active
\protected\def ं{\doulo ũ}
\protected\def\viramacheck{%
    \ifischar{्}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
        \ifischar{ा}{\egroup}{%
            \ifischar{ी}{\egroup}{%
                \ifischar{ू}{\egroup}{%
                    \ifischar{ि}{\egroup}{%
                        \ifischar{ु}{\egroup}{%
                            \ifischar{े}{\egroup}{%
                                \ifischar{ै}{\egroup}{%
                                    \ifischar{ो}{\egroup}{%
                                        \ifischar{ौ}{\egroup}{%
                                            \ifischar{अ}{\egroup}{%
                                                \ifischar{आ}{\egroup}{%
                                                    \ifischar{ई}{\egroup}{%
                                                        \ifischar{ई}{\egroup}{%
                                                            \ifischar{उ}{\egroup}{%
                                                                \ifischar{ऊ}{\egroup}{%
                                                                    \ifischar{ए}{\egroup}{%
                                                                        \ifischar{ऐ}{\egroup}{%
                                                                            \ifischar{ओ}{\egroup}{%
                                                                                \ifischar{औ}{\egroup}{%
                                                                                    ə\egroup
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
काखीडूअए क की ा क्\\
क् क का कि की कु कू के कै को कौ कं\\
ढ ढा ढि ढी ढु ढू ढे ढै ढो ढौ ढह\\
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: You don't need the `\blank` command here, I think, as it just expands to an empty replacement text.

Comment: Indeed! I changed the code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have the right fonts available on my system, this is kind of a shot in the dark. The idea is to have nested `\ifx` checks, like the following structure:

```
\ifx\tmp X
\else
  \ifx\tmp Y
  \else
  \fi
\fi
```

Because you are using `\@gobble` to remove the following token from the input stream, you have to be a bit more careful, because TeX leaves parts of the `\else`/`\fi` structure in the token stream. So the `\@gobble` would remove these tokens instead of the following character (this is why you have `\expandafter` in your test). For nested ifs putting the right number of `\expandafter`s is too tedious.

What you can use instead is a macro like

```
% use as \ifischar{X}{then part}{else part}
\def\ifischar#1{%
    \ifx\tmp#1%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
```

which performs the same check but takes care no spurious tokens are left in the token stream. Your `\viramacheck` macro would then become

```
\protected\def\viramacheck{%
    \ifischar{्}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
    \ifischar{a}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
    \ifischar{b}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
    \ifischar{c}{\egroup\@gobble}{%
        ə\egroup
    }}}}%
}
```

I think this gives the correct result, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but probably something weird happened to the code. Please see the edit.

Comment: Should I make one MWE with English characters? The only risk with English characters is if I make them active some commands may go wrong. If you can guide me how to avoid that, I'll make one example in English for this problem.

Comment: You removed the `\makeatletter` from your updated code

Comment: Oh! I did not remove it, but it was in a wrong place. Now when I put it back everything is fine. I even worked it out with my script and it was fine there too. Just one last difficulty. Please see the edit.